# Is there a database of C function signatures?

Tags: c, clang, interop, ffi, abi

Looking at the [MicroHs source code](https://github.com/augustss/MicroHs/blob/685b2a193dd58cd099554e875d45755432f2a30f/src/runtime/eval.c#L1043), it has listings of C functions with their signatures, such that they can be used in Haskell's FFI:

```
 * The types are
 *   V    void    name(void)
 *   i    int     name(void)
 *   I    value_t name(voi)
 *   IV   void    name(value_t)
 *   II   value_t name(value_t)
 *   IIV  void    name(value_t, value_t)
 *   III  value_t name(value_t, value_t)
 *   DD   flt_t  name(flt_t)
 *   Pi   int     name(void*)
 *   PI   value_t name(void*)
 *   PP   void*   name(void*)
 *   iPi  int     name(int, void*)
 *   PPI  value_t name(void*, void*)
 *   PPP  void*   name(void*, void*)
```

and then

```
  { "log",      (funptr_t)log,     FFI_DD },
  { "exp",      (funptr_t)exp,     FFI_DD },
[...]
  { "fgetc",    (funptr_t)fgetc,   FFI_Pi },
  { "fputc",    (funptr_t)fputc,   FFI_iPi },
```

I am wondering whether such a table can't be generated automatically?

The C compiler knows about the ABIs on my system, so if it has compiled the C library, it should also contain information about the signature of e.g. `log` and `fgetc`.

How would I generate this listing automatically?

Comment: If you have the debug compiled C library, [Finding function parameters for functions in shared object libraries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104468/finding-function-parameters-for-functions-in-shared-object-libraries) may help some.

Comment: Unless you've stripped the binary, you should be able to use the same signature information that debuggers use.